# What is the advantage of regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

The regular Expression of code

```
    String inputOne = "cat cat cat cattie cat";
    String findStr = "cat";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputOne);
    int countOne = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        countOne++;
    }
    System.out.println("Match number " + countOne);
```

String comparison of code

```
   String inpuTwo = "cat cat cat cattie cat";
   int lastIndex = 0;
   int count = 0;
   while (lastIndex != -1) {
       lastIndex = inpuTwo.indexOf("cat", lastIndex);
       if (lastIndex != -1) {
            count++;
            lastIndex += findStr.length();
       }
   }
   System.out.println("Match number " + count);
```

In both will do find the occurrences of substring "cat" in a input string "cat cat cat cattie cat".

My questions is what is the difference between them?

What is the advantage in regular expression over string comparison.

Which one i should use for applications. regular expression or string comparison?.

Thanks.

Comment: It is short and consise.

Comment: What would you do if you had to find an email address in your string? You could argue that you could find occurrences of `@`. But then `@` can occur even outside the context of email addresses. It gets complicated until you can find a regex to solve the problem.

Comment: @adarshr Hypothetically iterate characters and check with flags checking if certain characters such as @ have been already matched. Not that it EVER is a good idea.

Comment: Try yourself this scenario: put both piece of code into a loop with 100K iterations and compare performances.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two are completely different, so the answer depends a lot on the task at hand.

If you use regular expressions without [*metacharacters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter), use string-based comparisons instead: they are easier to understand, and do not introduce complexity where it does not belong ([here is a link to an article that explores this point in depth](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)).

The power of regular expressions starts with the use of metacharacters. If you need to define strings that you want captured rather than enumerating them one by one, then regular expressions should be used.

Comment: Is regexp will use String comparison internally.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Most likely, no: regex engines usually build final state automata that recognize the input. In Java, building of that automaton happens in the call to `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Correct, by "string-based comparisons" I mean the various methods such as `indeOf`, `replace`, etc. that interpret `String`s as sequences of characters (as opposed to, say, `replaceAll` and `split(String)`, which interprets strings as regular expressions).

Answer (score 4):

The example you gave is INCREDIBLY basic. Maybe regex really isn't the best answer for that situation. Regex has many uses. I use regular expressions a lot in ETL work where I'm trying to identify a piece of information and pull it out. Frequently I'll mix in lookbehinds, capture groups, and character sets. Using advanced regular expressions are a LOT easier than doing things programatically.

An example would be that a friend of mine needed a regular expression that got valid money amounts out of a string whether or not they had commas.. and if they did only if there were three. The regex I wrote for that is:

> (?<=\$)\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*.\d{2}(?!\d)

`(?<=\$)` is a positive lookbehind. This is saying that $ has to be before the main match but not included.

`\d{1,3}` is looking for anywhere from 1 to 3 numbers.

`,?` matches a comma, but makes it optional.

`\d{3}` is again, 3 numbers.

Having all that in a group with `*` after it matches 0 or more of that sequence.

`\.\d{2}(?!\d)` makes sure we have cents but only 2 digits worth. the `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead and means that there can NOT be another digit after the main match. If there is that invalidates the match.

This regex would be SIGNIFICANTLY harder to write programatically and would take a lot of time. Using regexes saves time and, if you understand the regex, makes it a lot easier to see what's going on at a glance.

This regex matches things such as:

$1,000,000.00 and $100000.00

but would NOT match something like:

$1,00,000.00 or $1000.000

Commas can then be stripped out of the matched value and then you can parse it to a numeric data type.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, either is fine.  The regular expression one is a bit clearer to read, but not significantly.

The real advantage of regular expressions comes from when you need to do something more complicated.  For example, how would you write non-regular expression code to find the number of times you have two digits in a row?  (and you could, but it would be longer code and harder to read)

The regular expression would be "\d\d".  Writing this without the regular expression would require a lot of if statements.

Comment: \d{2} works as well and would be more readable IMO.

Comment: I use {n} for three or more.  Personal preference.  I think because \d\d is one character shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are useful when inbuilt functionality is not sufficient for particular scenario like we are look into do complex things. But some cases we can use either inbuilt functions or regex. Also use of regex will shorten the code and effective but reduce the readability of code I think.